# Linux terminal ping but only True/False

Tags: shell, ping

How can I test the accessibility of the web address with *ping* command but so that it only returns True or False? Similar to PowerShell's

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName address.com -Quiet
```

I googled it but that's it.

Comment: You can write a shell script with if else.

Comment: What is the result your powershell command returns? Any output? Or just a return value?

Comment: The result I want to achieve is "True" or "False" from the terminal. And with option -Quiet the PS will do exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ping -c1 address.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This issues one ping, doesn't output anything, and returns a 0/true if it worked, a positive error code if it failed, to the shell.

You can query it with `echo $?`.

If you just need to use the positive result:

```
if ping -c1 address.com >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo Yup
fi
```

Comment: @LenaMori what do you mean "more complicated"? Just the test is 13 characters less to type ... ;)